# How to Redirect if API call fails in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router

I'm trying to implement Redirect in my react js App so if API call returns status other that 200, I can redirect users to according pages. The problem is that Redirect doesn't work. My code so far:

```
function catchErr(res) {
    try {
        if (res.status === 200) {
            return res.json();
        } else if (res.status === 404) {

        <Redirect to="/404" // doesn't redirect to this route
         console.log("404") // prints 404
            throw Error(res.status);
        } 
        else {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.data;
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}


export async function getData() {

    let getParams = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    };

    const data = await fetch(url, obj)
        .then((res) => catchErr(res))

        .then((res) => {
            return res.data;
        });

    return data;
}
```

My api call is a function in separate file, it's not react functional component so I can't use useState hook to store state or use useHistory(history.push) inside getData() function. At the moment api call works great, catchErr() console.loges 404 if res.status === 404 but doesn't redirect to "/404" as I need to.  I can't figure out why Redirect wouldn't work in this case, please help.

Comment: You can't call JSX like that in the middle of a function. You'll need to refactor your code to handle the failures in a React component and either set some state to conditionally render a `Redirect` component into the DOM or access the `history` object to do an imperative redirect, i.e. `history.replace`. Since you've provided zero React code I can't make more targeted suggestion.

Comment: @Drew Reese, thank you for reply. Could you please share a code for history replace?  I'm just importing getData in my in my react component and using it as `` const [newData,setNewData] = useState()                                             
   let data = await getData                                       
 setNewData(data) ``

Answer (score 0):

You can't call JSX like that in the middle of a function. You'll need to refactor your code to handle the failures in a React component and either set some state to conditionally render a `Redirect` component into the DOM or access the `history` object to do an imperative redirect, i.e. `history.replace`.

Here's an example component using `history.replace`.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      // set any loading state
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        // process response, throw error if STATUS 404
      } catch(error) {
        // handle any error responses and redirect
        history.replace("/404");
      } finally {
        // clear any loading state
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  ...

  return (
    <div>My JSX</div>
  )
};
```

Comment: thank you for the example. But I need to have fetch functions in a separate file because I'll have more than 25 api calls and they need to be in the same file. I know that I could use history.push also if I'll use fetch API in a functional component, but I need a solution for separate function.

Comment: @new_reactjs This is mostly an example for ***where*** to use the `history` object in the fetching chain. My suggestion would be to refactor your API functions to take success & failure callbacks so they are more agnostic and decoupled from any specific UI use-cases. They should make a request and indicate success with response, or failure with error.